# Is there a React (state related) event pub sub pattern when replacing Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, publish-subscribe

It seems to me the trend is replacing Redux with React Context API and useReducer.

I personally do not like a huge store at root with states from user data to if a dialog is opened all mixed together.

Switching to React Context API allowed me to push the state down and closer to where they will be used. However I can only push it down to the level that child components are either displaying or modifying that value. For example:

```
<Parent>
  <CounterDisplay/>
  <CounterIncreaseButton/>
</Parent>
```

I have to have count on Parent and create a Context. Within the Context, I'll add the count value and an increaseCount method (or a state and a dispatch function when use reducer pattern). Then I provide the context to those 2 child components. Now one can display it and one can modify it.

Now what if I need another button located far from this part of the component tree that also need to change the count value? I have to lift the state up and maybe all the way to the root. That feels strange to me.

2nd issue is when states are scattered at multiple level along the path in the tree, when something happens say user click a button, you may need to call multiple functions from multiple contexts (or dispatch multiple actions, one for each state that may or may not change). Unlike when use Redux since everything is at the root, you just need to dispatch one action.

So what if instead I have an event pub/sub at the root level? I can have the counter state and code manipulate it pushed down even more to CounterDisplay. CounterDisplay need to subscribe to the pub/sub system and listen to the event and update counter correspondingly. And whichever component want to change the counter can just raise an event.

What am I missing in this pattern? Circular event loop? Raise conditions? Feels a good pub/sub library can prevent these. I looked around and did not find something existing. I looked at RxJS but don't feel that fits.

Thanks in advance for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

You've basically just described the exact reason for Redux to exist :)

Redux *is* "an event pub/sub at the root level", and can specifically be beneficial in cases where widely separated components need to make use of the same data.

You may want to read my post [Redux - Not Dead Yet!](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet/), which describes how Redux fits into today's ecosystem (including comparisons vs context) and some of the reasons you might find it useful.

Comment: Thank you @markerikson. Is it possible to use Redux but have state saved (together with logic changes the state (reducer??)) at the lowest possible level? What if in Redux store I have one state that saves the latest action. Components can map it (like subscribe). And handles the change accordingly. Would that cause a lot of re-rendering? And also feels something simpler can do that.

Comment: That also basically sounds like [React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) :)  Its major purpose is to let your React components access the specific state they care about, and only re-render those components when those specific pieces of state are updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are put off redux by the amount of boilerplate.
I would suggest taking a look at `redux-zero`.

Under the hood. `react-redux` uses a context provider at the root.
When you use the `connect` Higher-Order-Component that is using the `context`.
Same with the redux hooks.

So it's quite normal to have the provider at the very top.
It would be the same for any library like the `react-router` to do the same.

I would suggest you keep trying without redux so you can learn more. Put the provider at the root. It won't impact performance in anyway.
**Isolate the context you create and the provider to a singleton file and import it to the components you need**

Comment: I do not mind the boilerplate. What I don't like the state and reducers are far away from where they are being used. In Redux case, they are at the root. With Context API, it got pushed down but components modify state but not use it (eg. CounterIncreaseButton) keep it up. And I just want to fire one event/action (which Redux does).

Comment: @GordonSun The common pattern is to have your reducer in the same file directory as the component group that uses that state.
Then you import all the reducers in the different places under `combineReducers` functionality.